# How to determine whether a value is in a List<string>?

Tags: c#, arrays

In C# using VS2005, let's say I have a `List<string>` called `listOfStrings` and a `string` variable called `str`.

Can I do something like this?

```
if (str in listOfStrings) { ... }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can. Have a look at the [`List<T>.Contains(..)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) method.

```
List<string> l = new List<string>();
l.Add("Hello");
l.Add("World");

if (l.Contains("Hello"))
{
    // ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`List.Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) to do this.